# Chrome developer tools console showing faded Javascript object property, why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I've logged a Javascript Object to find a property.
But it appears some of them are faded.

[image]

Is that private propeties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not private, just non-enumerable. It means if you iterate over your object with a `for..in` loop, the loop will skip them. You can still access them directly by name.

Properties you add to the object are enumerable by default. You can make them non-enumerable by calling e.g. `Object.defineProperty(obj, 'ytd_sale', { enumerable: false });`

More info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty